# EXTJS : How to display multiple grid on single page?

Tags: extjs

I would like to display multiple grid on page, grid should not overlap each other and all the grid should populate horizontally , every request should create a new grid on the same page so that we can compare the data very easily across the grid. Please help me how to do that in the EXTJS. I don't have much idea of EXTJS.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to generate grids dynamically or their quantity is static? can you provide you code to work with?
is your answer as simple as :

```
{
    xtype:"container",
    height: 353,
    width: 994,

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'string',
                            text: 'String'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'string',
                            text: 'String'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'string',
                            text: 'String'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a main panel and set its layout to hbox,then add grids dynamically to that panel's item list on user's request